# Individual resources for wildcard subdomains

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have multiple subdomains all using a common virtual server and entry point `/var/www/index.php`, and this file uses `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to determine the applicable "site" which is used to control the resulting HTML.

```
site1.example.com
site2.example.com
site3.example.com
...
siteN.example.com

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    <Directory "/var/www">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I wish for each of these subdomain sites to have individual public image resources available to them.  To do so, I have currently just added individual directories for each site which are available to all sites

```
/var/www/public/site1/image1.png
/var/www/public/site1/image2.png
/var/www/public/site1/image3.png

/var/www/public/site2/image4.png
/var/www/public/site2/image5.png
```

And then use PHP to write the appropriate path based on `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

```
<img src="/public/site1/image1.png" alt="bla" >
```

Given this scenario, is it possible to use Apache (or maybe PHP or Linux symbolic links) do not require the subdomain in them?

```
<img src="/public/image1.png" alt="bla" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be achievable using .htacces. You need to implement the following:

```
if($domain is 'site1.host.com')
{
    rewrite '/public/image1.png' to '/public/site1/image1.png'
}
```

This is not tested, and may require adding other images extensions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.host\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/public/(.*\.png)$ /public/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

EDIT.  The below appears to work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.host\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^public/([^//]+)$ public/%1/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Could it be accomplished with wildcards instead of hardcoding `site1`?

Comment: @user1032531 I am not sure, that $1 and $2 will work. But this is the way we must move. Plz, try the updated htaccess.

Comment: Tested, but doesn't work.  log shows strip per-dir, then applying patter, but then pass through, and results in a missing file.

Comment: Needed to get rid of `/` at start of RewriteRule.  Now rewrites, but doesn't insert $1 from RewriteCond.

Comment: @user1032531 Thanks for editing, it's hard to test .htaccess